# history.push inside IFRAME is reloading the IFRAME page continuously using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, browser, react-router

I'm trying to use `history.push()` using react router v5. My website is embedded into another main site as an iframe. When `history.push()` is used I'm observing a strange behaviour that my website which is inside the iframe is continuously reloading.

Note : This is happening in all browsers.

[Link to demo](https://react-router-issue-server.web.app/)

[Link to Code](https://github.com/akarshjairaj/react-router-infinite-reload-issue-in-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

A recursive call without base condition was identified due to which infinite calls were made which leaded to continuous reload.
[Link for the bug fix](https://github.com/akarshjairaj/react-router-infinite-reload-issue-in-iframe/commit/f359b023a94a7223ae44bfcd044be0f154d6c742#diff-b46eedaa1ae8bcab13b53d735016b5c34e2d56466f7cd857f82accd1eb7d3be9L62)